# Detecting JSpinner button events

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, look-and-feel, jspinner

I need to create some JSpinner controls where I can detect the button presses, *whilst using the current look and feel*. I have found I can do this easily enough as follows:

```
class CustomSpinnerUI extends BasicSpinnerUI {
    @Override
    protected Component createNextButton() {
        // Add custom ActionListener.
    }

    @Override
    protected Component createPreviousButton() {
        // Add custom ActionListener.
    }
}
```

The problem is that by doing this I end up with a nasty-looking spinner which doesn't use the same look and feel as the rest of my UI. I'm currently using `Nimbus` but I need to support different L&F configurations.

I thought about possibly setting up some sort of dynamic proxy, but couldn't find any suitable `Spinner` interfaces to enable me to do that.

Can anyone think of a way around the problem? I figure I either need to get at the button `ActionListeners` without subclassing `BasicSpinnerUI`, or work out a way to have my `CustomSpinnerUI` use the correct L&F.

Edit: "default look and feel" -> "current look and feel".

Comment: same question as always ... why?

Comment: I have some time and date spinners that need to share the same `Calendar` instance. It's for a touchscreen so just having a single spinner is too fiddly. If there's a better way to approach the problem I'd love to hear suggestions, but wanted to try and keep the question clear...

Comment: @Baqueta for Touch_Screen (I only image about acceptable size for finger on LCD) would be better look for JFormattedTextField with Date/DateTime/Time Formatter and with two JButtons (one of the left other on the right side ) with Icon,

Comment: still dont see the connection: what have the buttons to do with the shared Calendar? Implement a custom spinnerModel (which share a Calendar) and let the spinner instances share that model ...

Comment: @kleopatra I took a quick look at that option but it was looking like I'd need to override and re-implement most of the methods in `SpinnerDateModel`. Intercepting the button events seemed less risky and more flexible. If I can't find a workaround for the L&F issue try taking that route.

Comment: the SpinnerDateModel is ... ehem ... (mildly put) suboptimal implementation anyway. For real-world applications, you'll need something to set the calendar anyway ;-) Plus: _model_ is the way to go in Swing whenever you have a _model_ related requirement (which seems to be the case in yours)

Comment: @kleopatra On reflection I think I agree with you that it would be better to keep to MVC conventions. I looked into the shared calendar & model approach a bit more and  I've run into problems with that approach too. I'm going to put up a separate question for that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a dirty technical answer to (concededly assumed) problem "how to access the buttons for hooking-in a custom actionListener" is to loop through the spinner's children and add the listeners to the buttons, identified by their name:

```
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
    Action action = new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            LOG.info("button " + ((Component) e.getSource()).getName());
        }
    };
    for (Component child : spinner.getComponents()) {
        if ("Spinner.nextButton".equals(child.getName())) {
            ((JButton) child).addActionListener(action);
        }
        if ("Spinner.previousButton".equals(child.getName())) {
            ((JButton) child).addActionListener(action);
        }
    }
```

- that's dirty because it relies on an undocumented implementation detail which a LAF may or may not respect: Metal, Nimbus do; Win doesnt (which I consider an oversight but that's a different story :-)
- it is technical only, as the real problem seems to be somewhere else, judging by a recent comment on the question

Comment: +1 maybe that job for some of JCalendar, JDatePicker, finally for most complex SwingX Calendar

Comment: A dirty answer, but it seems like I was taking the wrong approach to the problem in the first place...